# C reading from file, it reads "@"

Tags: c, file, file-processing

I am trying to read a file in C. But when I read, and write it to stdout it prints @ also which there is no in my file. What is the reason?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main() {

FILE *fp;
int br;
char buffer[10];
int i;
fp = fopen("a.txt","r");
while(1) {
        br = fread(buffer,1,10,fp);
        printf("%s",buffer);
        if (br==0)
                break;
        }
}
```

Output:

1234567891@2345678912@3456789
12@3456789
12@

The file:
123456789123456789123456789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically allocate your buffer and have it be initialized to zeros like this:

```
  char *buffer = calloc(1, 11);

   <do your read loop>

   free(buffer)
```

This way you get the zero byte at the end which will terminate the string when printing it. When C prints a string it expects it to be terminated by a NULL (or 0) byte.

Comment: This is wrong if you allocate the buffer outside of the loop, as not every read must end up with reading exactly 10 characters (particularly true for the last read). It would be all right if you allocated buffer inside of the loop, but don't think it's the right way to go.

Comment: Yes, this is a very special case. The more general way would be to zero the byte beyond the read by simply assigning it to zero.

Comment: I am trying to vote up but I get an error says: Vote up requires 15 reputation.

Comment: I think you might get more reputation as you accept more answers. You should look back at the previous answers to your question and either accept them (or give your own and accept it if you worked it out).

Answer (score 6):

Your `fread` call reads up to 10 bytes correctly, but `printf` with `%s` requires string to be null terminated. You can fix it by increasing size of the buffer to be 11 bytes and after every call to `fread` write zero at the end of data, i.e. `buffer[br] = 0;`.

The other way to go is to tell `printf` what is the size of your data by calling `printf("%.*s", br, buffer);`. You don't need to modify your buffer array then.

Comment: You actually only need to write the null byte once; `fread` won't change it. Also, OP needs to beware the return value of `fread`; it can return less data than asked for.

Comment: @derobert because, as you said, `fread` can return less data than asked for, you need to write the null byte after every call if you don't want to have garbage included from a previous call.

Comment: @tomasz yes, that's correct. I misread and didn't notice that you were using `br` as the subscript. So, yeah, your example is doing the right thing. (Alternatively, you could also use `fwrite` instead of `printf`, of course)